# How to change the name of root when sending mail

Tags: debian, email, postfix, exim, root

I would like mail sent from root to be sent as `HOSTNAME <noreply@example.com>`.

On my outgoing-only servers that run exim4, I simply modify the file `/etc/passwd` and change the name of root to `HOSTNAME`. Then I go to `/etc/email-address` and add the line `root: noreply@example.com`. Any mail sent from root, looks like `HOSTNAME <noreply@example.com>`.

In postfix, I can create a generic mapping `generic.db` and have root send email as `noreply@example.com` but I can't change the name field to hostname, it just appears as the email address.

Any idea how I can accomplish this in postfix?

Debian 8.2 / Postfix

Comment: You could just have the application write the header the way you want it to appear.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it's not changing it. One application for example is Logwatch. I changed the 'From' but postfix or the system is overriding it. The exim4 servers seem to accept the changes I described so not sure why I can't do this with postfix.